# rookie issue: AWTException cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: exception, awtrobot, resolve

I'm sorry for asking what is probably a very simple question, but my google-fu skills are failing me here. All I want to do is have a simple robot click around and type stuff.

here is the whole of my class thus far:

```
import java.awt.Robot;
    public class Geniebot extends Robot {
        public Robot bot;
        //this is the actual robot

        public Geniebot(){
            try{
                Robot r = new Robot();
            }
            catch (AWTException e){
                throw new RuntimeException("something is wrong");
            }
        }

}
```

and eclipse is underlining AWTException in red and saying that it cannot be resolved to a type.

Comment: You'll need to paste the contents of your `Robot` constructor, too. It sounds like you didn't initialize AWT, or you're trying to access stuff before it's properly initialized. Dig into the inner details of the exception (or at least the message).

Answer (score 2):

You have to import `java.awt.AWTException`. Add it to your import list or use `Ctrl + Shift + O` to let Eclipse do it for you.